# Bower version resolving when using git URLs

Tags: git, bower

When using bower with git URLs the following example

```
{
    "name" : "myapp",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies" : {
    "mylib" : "http://host/git/mylib.git#2.13"
}
```

actually resolves to the `2.13.1` tag which is also present.

```
bower mylib#2.13 resolve http://host/git/mylib.git#2.13
bower mylib#2.13 checkout 2.13.1
```

Why does it behave this way? How can I fix it to use actually the 2.13 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower works with [semver](http://semver.org/) versions. A valid version should follow the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH convention.
You are using a Bower endpoint in the `<package>#<version>` form where  is a valid range, commit, branch, etc.
The version you specified - 2.13 - is not a valid semver version so Bower treats it as a [version range](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#ranges). 2.13 is actually an [X-Range](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#x-ranges-12x-1x-12-) - 2.13.x - which means a version `>=2.13.0 <2.14.0`.
2.13.1 is probably the version which best satisfies this version range.